# How to handle the test failure in cypress

Tags: cypress

Usecase:

I have a web page and have to validate the text. text verification page its kind of pane. So if test case passed, automatically cypress will execute the next block of code to close the pane. if failure, it simply skip the next code and start to execute next "it" block. I just need to refresh the page if any failure or i need to execute to close pane code if any failure. Please suggest how to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to ensure that in case of failure, other tests can start from the known position is to use `beforeEach` hook. Put there code responsible for opening certain page or pane, so each test will start from the same view. This way, no matter if the previous test failed or succeed.

Further read: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks